# Weird artifacts when rendering on Nvidia GPU

Tags: cycles-render-engine, uv, shaders, gpu, artifacts

For some reason, when rendering on my RTX 2060 in Blender, I'm getting these weird flickering artifacts.

[image]

As can be seen from the above screenshot, my node setup is a cube compressed into a plane by some simply vector maths with a musgrave texture applied to it. These artifacts are only appearing when rendering with the GPU (this includes the final render), and on CPU the scene renders just fine.

How can I fix this? Is something from with my card, or is this some Blender bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are reducing the z axis to 0 the top and bottom faces are z-fighting with each other.

I get the exact same thing on my end, by the way, and I'm also perplexed as to why the CPU doesn't face this issue.

I tried to work out a solution using *Backfacing*, but failed.

Instead of leaving the z disconnected you can divide it by some large number and get a workaround.

[image]

Comment: That makes sense, but why does this only occur on the GPU?

Comment: I'm curious about it as well, but I can't find anything right now.

Comment: @ArihanSharma I've updated with a workaround